# Arranging two different time series and averaging the data points ON MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have two different  date vectors timeA and timeB recorded by two sensors A and B.  TimeA is continuous while timeB is random i.e data wasn't recorded in sensor B for many hours. I need to arrange the data according to the data availability of sensor B and need to do hourly averaging. How can I approach this? Any help will be appreciated.

The starting period of both the sensor is different i.e A starts from 2019-06-23 12:00:01 while B starts from 2019-06-27 3:00:01and B ends at 2019-06-29 9:00:01and again B starts after some days

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions more closely. Only one of those tags is at all relevant.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find the overlap of two vectors by calling `intersect`. If the sensors are not exactly recording at the same time you might need to round the timestamps to get matches.